# Queued triggered sends in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

I have an active Journey, which was working as expected. Now the emails are not being sent.

The email has ampscript in it, and when I preview this email in the content builder with the target data extension, which is originated from Salesforce data, the email runs with no error.

In the triggered sends from the Journey it shows that the emails have been queued.

My question is:

If an email experience error at the sending and gets stuck in the queue, will the next sends also be queued, even if they were supposed to be send, once there is no error in the ampscript?

Answer (score 2):

By default, all the Triggered Sends (with no errors) get queued behind when one of the emails fail (with error) during the send execution.

From my experience, this has been resolved by submitting a Salesforce request to remove the queuing of the TSD sends when an error has occurred during the send execution.

Comment: No, the emails don't get queued behind failed emails. This is incorrect information.

Comment: If you check the OP's question he hasn't mentioned anything about resolving the AMPscript error. please read the post carefully

Comment: My answer is based as per the last line, where he has clearly mentioned "once there is no error in the ampscript". And as per your solution, "By default, all the Triggered Sends (with no errors) get queued behind when one of the emails fail (with error) during the send execution." - no this is not how it works. The triggered sends with no errors are not queued. Kindly, re-check.

Comment: Could you please prove it where it says it doesn't @KratiGarg?

Comment: my experience is if there is an unhandled error "you didn't invoke the error in the code intentionally" all subsequent emails will be queued, as your triggered send interaction is paused regardless of wether the next email would have had an error or not. In Krati answer he acknowledged that you have to update the email activity in the journey for the sends to restart. This is because the send was paused and updating will restart and resume sends to the queue. This can sometimes be confusing as the triggered send status doesn't always get switched to paused after an error, even though it is.

Comment: @TravisNaughton Thank you for the explanation. I haven't updated the send because it wasn't switched to paused, so I assumed that it was still running.